# Como utilizar uma página personalizada no wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou criando um site no wordpress, tenho alguns modelos já prontos como: index.php, category.php, 404.php, single.php.

Criei uma página personalizada "blog.php" e direcionei um link para ela com:

```
href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/blog.php' ) ); ?>"
```

Isso me diz que a página não existe.

Comment: Eles são fora do wordpress? Se sim ele provavelmente está procurando esse arquivo `blog.php` na pasta raiz aonde está o index do wordpress

Comment: está na pasta do index.php sim

Comment: Com tão pouca informação não tem como saber de fato o que está acontecendo. Tentou acessar a rota direto pela url? seusite/blog.php ?

Comment: Estou montando a estrutura ainda, qual outra informação precisa? Sim já tentei, not found também.

Comment: Olá, Matheus, pode nos dar um pouco mais de informação sobre o contexto e o caso de uso? Estou presumindo que você está tentando criar um modelo personalizado para quando o visitante acessar www.exemplo.net/blog/ e 2) que esta página vai mostrar as últimas postagem. Estou certo? 

E aproveitando, você já verificou o manual de desenvolvedor para [hierarquia de template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) e este [gráfico interativo](https://wphierarchy.com/) da hierarquia.?

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá, oque você deve fazer é criar um template de página:

- Abra seu arquivo blog.php e na linha em seguida do <?php você adiciona:

  /* Template name: Blog */

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isso,

- Crie uma página no Wordpress > Página
- Na opção de "Atributos da página" você define ela como seu template.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> OBS: não esqueça de importar seu cabeçalho e seu footer.